# Can a Rails app launch a rack app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, rack

If I have a Ruby on Rails application running on my Apache shared server (with Mongrel), can I get it to launch/run another total separate Rack application?

Then could I possibly build a Rails app that manages other rails/rack apps? So it could tell what apps are running and start/stop them when I want. Or is each app trapped in it's own "sandbox"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Rails 3 you can setup the router to pass any Rack application to the matched route. See: [Action Dispatch](http://guides.rails.info/3_0_release_notes.html#action-dispatch).